# Why does my ajax call to JSON is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call to show a div with the information of a project but after trying different ways to make the call nothing renders on the HTML as normal on the HTML side I just made a DIV where it is supposed to render an I'm attaching the js I wrote.

```js
var proyectos;

$(document).ready(function (){
  $.ajax({
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:5501/info.json'
  }).done(function(resultado){
    proyectos = resultado.proyectos;
    var htmlProyectos = ''
    for (var i=0; i < proyectos.length; i++){
      htmlProyectos +=`
      <h1>lorem ipsum doloris ameris</h1>
      <div class='contenedorPrincipal col-6 my-5 p-2 border rounded bg-white'>
      <div class='row'>
          <div id='idProyecto' class='col-6 text-left'>ID: ${proyectos.id}</div>
          <div id='fechaProyecto' class='col-6 text-right'>${proyectos.fecha}</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
          <div id='tituloProyecto' class='col-12 text-center'><h1>${proyectos.nombre}</h1></div>
          <div id='descripcionProyecto' class='col-12 text-center'><p>${proyectos.descripcion}</p></div>
          <div id='linkProyecto' class='col-12 text-center text-primary'><p>${proyectos.link}</p></p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      `
    }
    document.getElementById('proyectos').innerHTML = htmlProyectos
  })
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what specific problem you're describing.  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  Is the AJAX request made?  Is the response what you expect?  When you use the script debugger in the `done()` callback function, what specifically happens?  Are the values what you expect?  What is the resulting output and how specifically does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue?   *"nothing renders on the HTML*"  is the last step of *many* - what (*actually*) happens before that step?  Are there any errors in the browser console?  Does the request get sent? (check in the browser network tab)  Does the browser network tab give an error (eg 404/500) or is it 200?  What's the response in the browser network tab?  What's the value of `resultado` in the `.done` callback?

Comment: add the `datatype: json` for the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I can't add comments because I don't have the expected reputation, but try this...

```
var proyectos;

$(document).ready(function (){
  $.ajax({
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:5501/info.json'
  }).done(function(resultado){
    proyectos = JSON.parse(resultado)
    let htmlProyectos = ''
    for (var i=0; i < proyectos.length; i++){
      htmlProyectos +=`
      <h1>lorem ipsum doloris ameris</h1>
      <div class='contenedorPrincipal col-6 my-5 p-2 border rounded bg-white'>
      <div class='row'>
          <div id='idProyecto' class='col-6 text-left'>ID: ${proyectos.id}</div>
          <div id='fechaProyecto' class='col-6 text-right'>${proyectos.fecha}</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
          <div id='tituloProyecto' class='col-12 text-center'><h1>${proyectos.nombre}</h1></div>
          <div id='descripcionProyecto' class='col-12 text-center'><p>${proyectos.descripcion}</p></div>
          <div id='linkProyecto' class='col-12 text-center text-primary'><p>${proyectos.link}</p></p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
      `
    }
    $('#proyectos').html(htmlProyectos);
  })
});
```

Comment: *"try this"* - Why, specifically?  What was the problem in the original code?  What did you change?  How does that change correct the problem?